# Better way to access component state while using decorator

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test my component, let say it's called `<TestComponent />`
The component uses decorator for using redux and I cannot change that, because if I change it, then I'll have to change the method in other components as well.

I am able to access the states of the component by using this code:

```js
describe("Component States After API Calls", ()=>{
        const wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store}><TestComponent/></Provider>)
        var testcomponent = wrapper.find("testcomponent")
        const expectedState = {
                isLoading: false,
                testdata: [],
                loaded: true,
                loading: false
            }
        it("Should match the expectedState", ()=>{
            expect(testcomponent.getNode().state).toEqual(expectedState)
        })
```

But I'm not sure if it's good enough, is there a better way in achieving the same result with less step?

Thank You